# Eclipse - .apk throwing out <activities>

Tags: android, manifest

Have a simple app with 2 activities. Works on USB / SYNC, but when I export it to get an .apk file, Mainfest.xml throws out any reference to the 2nd .

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.easy"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".Splash" android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".StartingPoint" android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.easy.STARTINGPOINT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

 </manifest>
```

The 1st activity (.Splash) gets deleted during compile. I've had this problem with my first project so I started over with a very simple one to see if its a continuing problem or my first project.
Seems to be a continuing problem.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have proguard configured to do that?

Comment: check the apk that is in your bin folder to see if it does the same thing. And when you say exported, do you mean exporting it and signing it with a release key?

Comment: The .apk file in the Bin folder works %100. No problems. And I ment Exported being - compiled. Can you tell me why the Bin file is good but not the .apk file made by exporting/compile?